# How to create scarlar value function that input multivalue function?

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to create t-sql scalar value function that  input string multivalued and that sould
return string1 + string2 + string3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not looking for this please let me know (Just an example)

First create a table with some values

like

```
create table tbl (id int, col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50))
insert into tbl values(1,'colval1','colval2','colval3')


CREATE FUNCTION fn_TestFunc
(   
    @param1 int
)
RETURNS  varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN   
    declare @result varchar(max)

    select @result =  Col1+ ',' + Col2 + ',' + Col3
    from tbl t
    where t.ID = @param1

    return @result


END
```

To execute the function **select dbo.fn_TestFunc(1)**

**Output:**

```
Col1Val , Col2Val , Col3Val
```

1 more example

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TestFunc]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @param1 int
)
RETURNS  nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @result varchar(max)
    SELECT @result= 
    (
        SELECT 
            CAST(Col1 AS varchar(max)) + ',' + CAST(Col1 AS varchar(max)) + '|'
        from tbl t
                where t.ID = @param1
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) 
    return LEFT(@result,LEN(@result) - 1)
END
```

**Output**

```
Col1Val , Col2Val
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tbl'.

Comment: Com on .. create a table by the name tbl with columns id(int), col1 (varchar), col2(varchar).. then run it will work

Comment: create table tbl
( id int, col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50))

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Concat
(   
    @string1 varchar(max),
    @string2 varchar(max),
    @string3 varchar(max)
)
RETURNS  varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN   
    declare @result varchar(max)

    Set @result =  @string1+ ',' + @string2 + ',' + @string3


    return @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Or are you looking for this(an example)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_MyFunc
(
    @param1 varchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @result varchar(max)
    set @result = @param1 + '-' + @param1 + '-' + @param1
    return @result
END
```

**Output**: `test-test-test` when executed with `select dbo.fn_MyFunc('test')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Concat
(   
    @string1 varchar(max),
    @string2 varchar(max),
    @string3 varchar(max)
)
RETURNS  varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN   
    declare @result varchar(max)

    Set @result =  @string1+ ',' + @string2 + ',' + @string3


    return @result


END

--SELECT dbo.fn_Concat('aa','bb','cc')
```